# Connect Localhost MongoDb To An App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am trying to setup a localhost MongoDB connection with a React, GraphQL application. Everything is setup and working fine to my knowledge. I have Compass install for visually viewing my MongoDB Dbs.

Server.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const models = require('./models');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

//--- I added the localhost MongoDb link below ---//

const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/graphql01/';
if (!MONGO_URI) {
  throw new Error('You must provide a MongoLab URI');
}

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => console.log('Connected to MongoLab instance.'))
    .on('error', error => console.log('Error connecting to MongoLab:', error));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}));

const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

module.exports = app;
```

I can verify the `mongod` service is running fine on the system. I can make a connection via Compass to the address above within the file. When I run the npm initialisation command, the app loads fine. however, when I use the `GraphiQL` interface to run a mutation command, I eventually get the error:
`TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

Please let me know if there is some info I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track, it should have been:

const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/graphql01';

IE: replace the http with mongodb & no forward-slash at the end.